# Cat file dealing with header?

Tags: git, cat

I'm running the following command to download a single file from git:

```
git archive --remote=ssh://host/pathto/repo.git HEAD README.md
```

The contents of the file are directed to terminal, before I see the contents of the README I have some header information, that looks like this:

```
pax_global_header00006660000000000000000000000064131063477050014520gustar00rootroot0000000000000052 comment=502c8004562eab49c105b2e294d8806c735c13a1 README.md000066400000000000000000000002771310634770500123510ustar00rootroot00000000000000
```

My end goal is to redirect the file locally like so:

```
git archive --remote=ssh://host/pathto/repo.git HEAD README.md > README.md
```

How do I deal with the header information so I end up with files that don't contain the header as text?

Comment: See also [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3642143/4500798). Had you looked into what `git archive` actually does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that piping into `tar xvf -` solved the issue:

```
git archive --remote=ssh://host/pathto/repo.git HEAD README.md  |  tar xvf -
```